# angularjs - Problems converting my time into a users local time

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm working on a blog like application in AngularJS and I'm trying to convert the creation time of a post to the time and timezone of a user so its synced with their time (Example: It displays a posts was posted '10 minutes ago' rather than saying'10 hours ago' for a user who may be somewhere far even though the post was made 10 minutes ago.)

I tryed creating a php script that converts the post's time using the users timezone but it didnt prove successful. Below is the code I have.

```
uno.controller('NewsPostCtrl', function($scope, fbAuth, _uno, $interval, $http, $routeParams){

   _uno.getTime($scope.post.createdAt, $scope.visitortimezone).success(function(data){
       $scope.post.createdAt = _uno.parseDate(data);
   });

});
```

The PHP Script:

```
<?php 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $offset = explode(' ', $data->zone)[1];
    $time = (empty($data->t)) ? 'now' : $data->t;

    $original = new DateTime($data->t);
    $timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $offset*3600, false);
    $modified = $original->setTimezone(new DateTimezone($timezoneName));    

    echo $original->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

I dont know why the script isnt properly converting the time, I specified the timezone name based on the offset depending on the users location but I'm not getting much luck. Is there anything im missing?

Comment: Have you looked into http://momentjs.com? It has an angular wrapper that you can use.

Comment: actually havent, gonna check it out now!

Comment: @Obaid does it allow for cross country time converions? like im trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think so, check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/light/

Comment: if times are UTC javascript will do adjustments

Comment: @Obaid Oh i see, now what if i want to pass a date and time and convert that instead of the current time ?